# Why this function is not working? PHP

Tags: php, function, curly-braces

This is the original function and this works perfectly...

```
    function delete_directory($dirname) {

  if (is_dir($dirname))
    $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);

    if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;

  while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                   unlink($dirname."/".$file);
              else
                   delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);
         }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
  }
```

I tried to do a version with curly braces and different names but it is not working and I'm not sure what the problem is

```
    function borrar_directorio ($carpeta) {

  if (is_dir($carpeta)) {

    $abrir_directorio = opendir($carpeta);

    if (!$abrir_directorio) {

      return false;
    }
  }

  while ($archivo = readdir($abrir_directorio)) {

      if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {

        if (!is_dir($carpeta."/".$archivo)) {
          unlink($carpeta."/".$achivo);

        } else {

          borrar_directorio($carpeta.'/'.$archivo);
        }
      }
    }

  closedir($abrir_directorio);
  rmdir($carpeta);
  return true;
}
```

What I'm missing? I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors? What is in your error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 'Why this function is not working?' should be i spent one more flag? or keep it as it is ? :D

Comment: @JayBlanchard no errors, just is not deleting the directory and its files

Comment: @HendraNucleo no, please :) , really I need help

Comment: Then there must be errors. Code doesn't "not work" without errors. do you know where your error logs are?

Comment: @ProfessorZoom dump the output, what you got there ?

Comment: The curly braces are not 100% right. `if (is_dir($dirname)) $dir_handle = opendir($dirname); ` => `if (is_dir($dirname)) { $dir_handle = opendir($dirname); }`. You bracketed too many things.

Comment: There is a typo error here: `if (!is_dir($carpeta."/".$archivo)) {
          unlink($carpeta."/".$achivo);

        }` where `$achivo` should be `$archivo`. The script seems to works well for me

Comment: @olibiaz you are right, #$# typo errors that was the problem, thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem in how you have written it is that if the folder does not exist or can not be opened due to permission restrictions or filesystem errors, the while loop will still run.

Here's how the original script should be written using curly-braces

```
  if(is_dir($carpeta))
  {
    $abrir_directorio = opendir($carpeta);
  }
  if(!$abrir_directorio)
  {
    return false;
  }

  while($archivo = readdir($abrir_directorio))
  { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I change my code to this way but still my problem was a typo error :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe scandir will help:

```
public static function delTree($dir) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // echo "$dir/$file \n";
        is_dir("$dir/$file")) 
            ? delTree("$dir/$file") 
            : unlink("$dir/$file");
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
}
```

If this function will not work, uncomment echo and you will see, which files it tries to delete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved my problem but I will try your code :)